# unable to figure jboss error

Tags: jndi, jboss5.x, postgresql-9.2

can someone figure out whats the error in jboss. when i enter localhost:8080 in url it says INVALID REQUEST. PLEASE CHECK URL.

I am using jboss 5.0.1

JBOSS_HOME: D:\Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA

JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\bin\java

JAVA_OPTS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dprogram.name=run.bat -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000

CLASSPATH: D:\Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA\bin\run.jar

```
===============================================================================

20:46:16,640 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting JBoss (Microcontainer)...
20:46:16,640 INFO  [ServerImpl] Release ID: JBoss [Morpheus] 5.0.1.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_0_1_GA date=200902231221)
20:46:16,640 INFO  [ServerImpl] Bootstrap URL: null
20:46:16,656 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home Dir: D:\Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA
20:46:16,656 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home URL: file:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/
20:46:16,656 INFO  [ServerImpl] Library URL: file:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/lib/
20:46:16,656 INFO  [ServerImpl] Patch URL: null
20:46:16,656 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Base URL: file:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/common/
20:46:16,656 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Library URL: file:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/common/lib/
20:46:16,656 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Name: default
20:46:16,656 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base Dir: D:\Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server
20:46:16,671 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base URL: file:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/
20:46:16,671 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Config URL: file:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/conf/
20:46:16,671 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home Dir: D:\Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default
20:46:16,671 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home URL: file:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/
20:46:16,671 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Data Dir: D:\Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\data
20:46:16,671 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Library URL: file:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/lib/
20:46:16,671 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Log Dir: D:\Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\log
20:46:16,671 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Native Dir: D:\Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\tmp\native
20:46:16,687 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Dir: D:\Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\tmp
20:46:16,687 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Deploy Dir: D:\Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\tmp\deploy
20:46:17,296 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting Microcontainer, bootstrapURL=file:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/conf/bootstrap.xml
20:46:17,859 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Initializing VFSCache [org.jboss.virtual.plugins.cache.CombinedVFSCache]
20:46:17,859 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Using VFSCache [CombinedVFSCache[real-cache: null]]
20:46:18,140 INFO  [CopyMechanism] VFS temp dir: D:\Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\tmp
20:46:18,156 INFO  [ZipEntryContext] VFS force nested jars copy-mode is enabled.
20:46:20,218 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_13,Sun Microsystems Inc.
20:46:20,234 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_13-b03)
20:46:20,234 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 11.3-b02,Sun Microsystems Inc.
20:46:20,234 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows XP 5.1,x86
20:46:20,265 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
20:46:22,593 INFO  [ProfileServiceImpl] Loading profile: default from: org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.SerializableDeploymentRepository@126c5a5(root=D:\Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server, key=org.jboss.profileservice.spi.Pro
fileKey@143b82c3[domain=default,server=default,name=default])
20:46:22,593 INFO  [ProfileImpl] Using repository:org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.SerializableDeploymentRepository@126c5a5(root=D:\Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server, key=org.jboss.profileservice.spi.ProfileKey@143b82c3[doma
in=default,server=default,name=default])
20:46:22,593 INFO  [ProfileServiceImpl] Loaded profile: ProfileImpl@1e779a7{key=org.jboss.profileservice.spi.ProfileKey@143b82c3[domain=default,server=default,name=default]}
20:46:24,421 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://127.0.0.1:9283/
20:46:30,656 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Stack Native Core
20:46:30,671 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] 3.0.5.GA
20:46:42,218 INFO  [JMXConnectorServerService] JMX Connector server: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:2290/jmxconnector
20:46:42,375 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail
20:46:44,015 WARN  [JBossASSecurityMetadataStore] WARNING! POTENTIAL SECURITY RISK. It has been detected that the MessageSucker component which sucks messages from one node to another has not had its password changed from the installat
ion default. Please see the JBoss Messaging user guide for instructions on how to do this.
20:46:44,031 WARN  [AnnotationCreator] No ClassLoader provided, using TCCL: org.jboss.managed.api.annotation.ManagementComponent
20:46:44,203 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version) - JBoss Inc.
20:46:44,203 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Setting up property manager MBean and JMX layer
20:46:44,656 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Initializing recovery manager
20:46:44,843 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Recovery manager configured
20:46:44,843 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Binding TransactionManager JNDI Reference
20:46:44,875 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Starting transaction recovery manager
20:46:45,453 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
20:46:45,453 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8218
20:46:45,453 INFO  [StandardService] Starting service jboss.web
20:46:45,453 INFO  [StandardEngine] Starting Servlet Engine: JBoss Web/2.1.2.GA
20:46:45,531 INFO  [Catalina] Server startup in 146 ms
20:46:45,562 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/invoker
20:46:46,156 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/jbossws
20:46:46,203 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/web-console
20:46:46,265 INFO  [[/web-console]] SystemFolder: Failed to init plugin, Resource not found: SystemFolder.bsh
20:46:46,296 INFO  [[/web-console]] J2EEFolder: Failed to init plugin, Resource not found: J2EEFolder.bsh
20:46:46,421 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/jboss-local-jdbc.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
20:46:46,531 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/jboss-xa-jdbc.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
20:46:46,578 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/jms-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
20:46:46,609 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/mail-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
20:46:46,640 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/D:/Jboss/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/quartz-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
20:46:46,796 INFO  [SimpleThreadPool] Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
20:46:46,843 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Quartz Scheduler v.1.5.2 created.
20:46:46,843 INFO  [RAMJobStore] RAMJobStore initialized.
20:46:46,843 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
20:46:46,843 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 1.5.2
20:46:46,843 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
20:46:47,531 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS' to JNDI name 'java:DefaultDS'
20:46:48,062 INFO  [ServerPeer] JBoss Messaging 1.4.1.GA server [0] started
20:46:48,296 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] Connector bisocket://127.0.0.1:4657 has leasing enabled, lease period 10000 milliseconds
20:46:48,296 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory@3dc250 started
20:46:48,359 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] Connector bisocket://127.0.0.1:4657 has leasing enabled, lease period 10000 milliseconds
20:46:48,359 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory@188ef97 started
20:46:48,406 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/A] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
20:46:48,406 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/ex] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
20:46:48,406 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/ExpiryQueue] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
20:46:48,406 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/B] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
20:46:48,406 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/C] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
20:46:48,421 WARN  [ConnectionFactoryJNDIMapper] supportsFailover attribute is true on connection factory: jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ClusteredConnectionFactory but post office is non clustered. So connection factory wil
l *not* support failover
20:46:48,421 WARN  [ConnectionFactoryJNDIMapper] supportsLoadBalancing attribute is true on connection factory: jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ClusteredConnectionFactory but post office is non clustered. So connection factor
y will *not* support load balancing
20:46:48,421 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] Connector bisocket://127.0.0.1:4657 has leasing enabled, lease period 10000 milliseconds
20:46:48,421 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory@2de670 started
20:46:48,421 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/D] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
20:46:48,421 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/MailQueue] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
20:46:48,421 INFO  [TopicService] Topic[/topic/testDurableTopic] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
20:46:48,421 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/DLQ] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
20:46:48,437 INFO  [TopicService] Topic[/topic/securedTopic] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
20:46:48,437 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/testQueue] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
20:46:48,437 INFO  [TopicService] Topic[/topic/testTopic] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
20:46:48,640 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=JmsXA' to JNDI name 'java:JmsXA'
20:46:48,703 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=PostgresDSDYPK' to JNDI name 'java:PostgresDSDYPK'
20:46:48,734 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/
20:46:50,312 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/ap
20:46:50,406 WARN  [JAXWSDeployerHookPreJSE] Cannot load servlet class: org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.HtmlAdaptorServlet
20:46:50,406 WARN  [JAXWSDeployerHookPreJSE] Cannot load servlet class: org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.html.ClusteredConsoleServlet
20:46:50,421 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/jmx-conso1e
20:46:50,500 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
20:46:50,531 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8218
20:46:50,546 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.0.1.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_0_1_GA date=200902231221)] Started in 33s:859ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to specify the binding address for the jboss server. For jboss5.x, the command will be like

`Jboss\jboss-5.0.1.GA\bin\run.jar -b0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Check your port number under /deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml, I think the problem is right there.
It should be like this ==>

```
<!-- A HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
   <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
    maxThreads="250" strategy="ms" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
    emptySessionPath="true"
    enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
    connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"/>
```

Check the port number!